# Centreon web API v2 endpoints return 500 - No route found

Tags: api, centreon-api

I run centreon 21.04 in a VM for some tests.

I imported the Centreon REST API v2 collection into Postman as described [here](https://docs.centreon.com/21.04/fr/api/rest-api-v2.html).
Some endpoints work like:

- `POST /login`
- `GET /logout`
- `GET /configuration/icons`
- `GET /monitoring/acknowledgements`
- `GET /platform/topology`

but most other endpoints return an error 500 with "No route found".
Example of response with the `/centreon/api/latest/monitoring/hosts` endpoint:

```
$ curl --location --request GET 'http://<VM_IP>:80/centreon/api/latest/monitoring/hosts' --header 'X-AUTH-TOKEN: mytoken'
{"code":500,"message":"No route found for 'GET /monitoring/hosts'"}
```

The X-AUTH-TOKEN header is set with the token retrieved via the `/login` endpoint.
I'm using the default admin user for which I enabled *Reach API Configuration* and *Reach API Realtime* in the web UI via `Configuration > Users > Contacts/Users > admin > Centreon Authentication`.

Any idea why this is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently some endpoints only work in the beta version of the API for now, so make sure you use the `/centreon/api/beta/` path in the URL